Diagrama entidad relacion powerBI
Necesito puedan orientarme en el modelado y verificar si el está bien planteado el diagrama entidad relación, es para hacer mis primeras prácticas en power bi. Las tablas Dim que creé no sé como relacionarlas con las tablas de cultivos.
Entiendo que luego estas van a estar conectadas a la tabla factcultivos. Para comenzar  a desarrollar medidas en la tabla dax que hice aparte.
he avanzado hasta aquí ...


Pregunta para otros - Esto sería que el usuario solicita información de terceros? realmente PowerBi no se si es algo que se atienda acá.

@Excorpion Power bi aplica, tiene su propio lenguaje. Además, que la pregunta es más de modelamiento de datos que a mi parecer también aplica (aunque creo que para la mayoría de los usuarios no)

No obstante, me parece que la pregunta es demasiado amplia. No se pregunta por un problema en específico "la tabla A con la tabla B están bien relacionadas, ya que busco guardar y consultar X cosa con Y requisitos" (porque el contexto del problema hace que algo esté bien o mal). En cambio, la pregunta vomita un modelo de más de 10 tablas, donde no sabemos dónde está el problema que el usuario cree tener y no sabes el contexto de lo que está modelando
